# How to import other file with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

now i'm doing add react to website from this tutorial [react Tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html). I don't run this react with node so i just build in with add DOM Container to the HTML. However i struggle to integrate other file in a same page. i share my code

this on file index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Add React in One Minute</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
 
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div> 
    <script type="text/babel" src="./App.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

this my code on app.js

```
 class App extends React.Component { 
    render() {
      return(
        <div>
           <img src="<logoURL>"/>

           <div id="homeSite"></div> 

           <script type="text/babel" src="./Home.js"></script>
           <script type="text/babel">
               ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById("homeSite"));
           </script>

        </div>  
      )
    }
  }
```

and this my code on home.js

```
class Home extends React.Component { 
  
    render() {
      return(
        <div >
            test home display text
        </div> 
      )
    }
  }
```

i got 2 warning error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

other is this

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
> (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
> component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
> default and named imports.

i not sure how to resolve this. please help

Answer (score 0):

In index.js you can not write html code, for html code you have to use index.html file that located in public dir.
in index.js write like below

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
 </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Comment: hi @Vishal if you see the tutorial link. you will know what i mean.

Comment: https://www.bezkoder.com/integrate-react-express-same-server-port/
https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-setup-nodejs-express-for-react/

Comment: you can find demo from above links.